# Error when using List in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Classes:

```
Class A
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<B> ExpenseList { get; set; }
}

Class B
{
public string Expense{ get; set; }
public decimal Money{ get; set; }
}
```

Suppose my data is as follows:

```
data:
{
0 Name: Carlos;
1 Name: Tom;
}
expense:
{
0 Expense: book; Money: 100;
1 Expense: fund; Money: 80; 
}
```

I want each `data` to have 1 list `expense`. And this is i use:

```
for(int i=0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
   for(int k=0; k < expense.Count; k++)
   {
      data[i].ExpenseList.Expense = expense[k].Expense;
      data[i].ExpenseList.Money= expense[k].Money; 
   }
}
```

I run the program and got the error. What did I do wrong? I do not know where the error is
Can somebody help me, thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Did you initialize the List?

Comment: Yes, I initialized the list ExpenseList

Comment: If you don't know what the error is, nobody here can help you. You need to debug your code and post the exception message you receive. Please read [ask]

Comment: This is the error I get:

'System.Collections.Generic.List<Website.ViewModels.B>' does not contain a definition for 'Expense' and no extension method 'Expense' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Website.ViewModels.B>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working with a list, not with an object. You need to create an object and then add to the list.

```
for(int i=0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
   for(int k=0; k < expense.Count; k++)
   {
      B toAdd = new B();
      toAdd.Expense = expense[k].Expense;
      toAdd.Money = expense[k].Money;
      data[i].ExpenseList.Add(toAdd);
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I understand the problem, i voted up for you. Thanks my man

Answer (score -1):

Initialize the list in constructor,it will solve to ur problem